# Parsing HTML to fix microtypography & glyph issues

Tags: php, localization, html-parsing, typography

I'm interested in [microtypography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microtypography) issues on the web.

I want a tool to fix:

- Quotes

  - “ (&#8220;) opening quote (instead of ")
  - ” (&#8221;) closing quote (instead of ")
- Apostrophe

  - ’ (&#8217;) apostrophe (instead of ')
- Dashes and Hyphens

  - – (&#8211; or &ndash;) en dash, used for ranges, e.g. “13–15 November” (instead of -)
  - — (&#8212; or &mdash;) em dash, used for change of thought, e.g. “Star Wars is—as everyone knows—amazing.” (instead of -, or --)
- Ellipsis

  - … (&#8230; or &hellip;) horizontal ellipsis, used to indicate an omission or a pause (instead of ...)
- And more \o/

All those fixes depend on the content language. In French, for example, we must add a insecable (non-breaking) space before every composed glyph (`:`, `;`, `…`, `?`, `!`, ...), and our quotes are « like this ».

There are many constraints for such a tool:

- it must not edit any HTML inside protected tags (`pre`, `code`...)
- it must be fast (used on a CMS output)
- it must not break the HTML
- and so on.

There already are some tools on the market:

- http://michelf.ca/projects/php-smartypants/typographer/
- http://kingdesk.com/projects/php-typography/
- http://code.google.com/p/typogrify/

They are all more or less based on SmartyPants, a 2005 lib, not tested, not documented, parsing HTML manually and not dealing with other rules than English. Hell no.

So my questions are:

- Do you know of any decent tool like this?
- How can I do it? I already have a POC using [DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) but I'm not convinced. What's the best way to parse and edit HTML in PHP?

---

**Edit July 2013**: I have developed [JoliTypo](https://github.com/jolicode/JoliTypo) from the tests and expertise I gained with this issue. No existing lib was doing what I wanted to do.

Comment: Great question, although I'm wondering if this isn't the sort of thing it would be better to process at the point where the data is saved, rather than the point where it is output? Especially if you have a lot of text (which is the case where this would be the most useful), it's hard to imagine processing for details (like distinguishing between appropriate em and en dash usage) in a manner efficient enough so that it won't drastically increase page loading times.

Comment: @MichaelCSchuller This should be handled by a cache system IMO. I think editing user submitted content and persisting it is a bad idea as there is no way to get the type-writed version back. Storing both the user and the converted text can be a solution for performance related issues.

Comment: That of course runs the risk of making the output's relationship to the input somewhat opaque to the user who is entering the original text, but I suppose that's a philosophical, rather than a technical question. One reason why I think things like Markdown are such a good solution for formatting text input is that you know exactly what transformations will be applied (and you can get back the original as it was entered, as you say).

Comment: may be make a sense of using perl regular expression for replacement. i can write some of itfor you [http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.pcre.php]

Comment: my best guess would be a series of functions that would execute being content aware, doing some checks before doing anything. Wordpress does this in a filthy way IMO, but it tries it's best to make the replacing, maybe you could be enlighted by their sources -not. Even though you want to avoid it, each language has it's own particularities and you can't run away from that.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regexes.  It can't be done reliably.  Use a proper DOM parser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My somewhat-friend Sean built something that I use for this purpose quite often. You can view the demo here: http://files.seancoates.com/lexentity/ he blogged about it here: http://seancoates.com/blogs/lexentity and you can grab the source here: https://github.com/scoates/lexentity

It might not meet your full language needs, but it's a start with English.

Comment: Nice thanks! It's on github, there is unit tests, I'm happy. But it's parsing HTML with regexes, and that's remind me of this blog post: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

I will look out and try it anyway - but that does not seams bulletproof to me.

Comment: As the article points out, there are many simple cases where using something like a regular expression is more sensible than a full blown HTML engine. The code in that case was designed to deal with articles for their http://phpadvent.org site. Your particular case of wanting to run it on the content portion of CMS output would seem to match. Also: Only solution I've got.

Comment: Regex-based solutions applied at the text string level is the right solution. Thx for the help, Lexentity is the best start point I could get. Enjoy the bounty ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Damien, Sean is quite responsive to improvements, so if you end up taking it further with new languages and such do submit pull requests :)

Comment: @Damien it uses regular expressions to generate tokens, not to parse HTML entirely. Many (most?) lexers use regular expressions to parse source into tokens. I fully agree that HTML should not be parsed with regex, but this is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/class.tidy.php). It is boundled with PHP 5+ (all you need to use it is libtidy). It not just parses HTML, but repairs it too.

But with the localization, you are on your own - [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) does not have any data about quotes - f.ex.; at least i could not found them.

Answer (score 2):

As about quotes read this [Q tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.2), others I would use bbcode library.
As it would be really difficult to write algorithm to distinguish between dashes You need. BBcode allows editor to choose, but in that case when editor has to make an action You may think of providing some kind of button to insert special characters.
For things that are easy to recognize, You just create new rules for BBcode lib and if they have to be local aware You would create different set of rules for different languages. Obvously inheritance in OOP would come handy here.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, a regex-based solution could be dangerous/forbidden...

But if you have a lock-down on the kind of content you want to use this tool on (and it sounds like you do if the content is coming from your CMS), it sounds like an extension to the Perl program Demoroniser could take care of this for you: http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/demoroniser/